# Raise flag if date exceeds 1 day / 24 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, case, date-arithmetic

I am trying to create a column that raises a flag when the duration is a day (24 hours or more) as of the date of initial date.

```
select 
    case when (enddte - begindte) > '23:59:59.000'  
        then '1' 
        else '0' 
    end as flag 
from shipment 
where ship_id = '14723'
```

Something to note:
The dates for enddte and begindte are formatted as follows i.g.: 2017-09-06 20:22:36.000

Would I need to further break down the case statement above calculating day - day and hours - hours?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...? Also, what are the datatypes of columns `begindte` and `enddte`?

Comment: @GMB: It looks like the OP is using MSSQL.  I updated the tags accordingly.  ALSO: I'm not sure how the OP is invoking this query, but I'm not sure "select case when" is the best approach...

Comment: @GMB, yes, I am using MSSQL. Data type is datetime.

I was thinking the query should possibly look something like this but haven't gotten it to work yet.  

select 
 case when (datediff(hour,enddte, begindte)/24.0) > 1 
  then '1' 
  else '0' 
 end as flag 
from shipment 
where ship_id = '14723'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datediff()` is not the good tool for this task. It increments by 1 every time a boundary is crossed, which produces somehow counter-intuitive results. Typically, the hour difference between today at 13:59 and today at 14:01 is 1.

You can use simple date arithmetics, as follows:

```
select s.*,
    case when enddte > dateadd(day, 1, begindte) then 1 else 0 end as flag
from shipment s
where ship_id = 14723
```

Of course, this assumes that the two columns are of a legitimate date-like datatype, such as `datetime` or `datetime2`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, I figured it out.

```
select 
    case 
        when (datediff(hour,enddte, begindte)/24.0) > 1 
            then '1' 
            else '0' 
        end as flag 
from shipment 
where ship_id = '1326747-2'
```